# function returns pointer to int

Tags: c++, pointers

My main() crashes below when add(4) is called.

As I understand int* add, it should return a pointer to integer. Then, I should be able in main to say:

int * a = add(3);

to return a pointer to int.

Please explain what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* add (int a) {
   int * c, d;
   d = a + 1;
   *c = d;
   cout << "c = " << c << endl; 
   return c;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 4;

    int * c;

    c = add(4); 

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: +1 - @Rubber boots is correct

Comment: No he's not. Reading comprehension, people. `*c = d` does *not* make `c` point to `d`!

Comment: Worse than that, you're writing to, and returning, an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: @all - oops I saw that and corrected the comment that when your complaints came. What do now? Should I strike out the modification? How to do that?

Comment: This is unreal, I figured when I clicked this it would be a scramble between 10 people to get the right answer in, and instead I find myself downvoting a half-dozen wrong answers

Comment: @rubber If you mouse over your comment you'll see an "x" appear at the end you can use to delete it

Comment: @Michael: Because other than the line `*c = d`, it's looks like a classic example of returning a pointer to a local.  Not to mention there's no reason at all to return an `int *` instead of an `int` here.

Comment: @Justin I suppose, but I would expect the lack of a `&` anywhere in the function to give people pause; I guess it was just the rush to get an easy answer in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In

```
 *c = d;
```

the pointer `c` is not initialized, so your program runs into undefined behavior. You could do something like the following instead:

```
void add( int what, int* toWhat )
{
    (*toWhat) += what;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
int initialValue = ...;
add( 4, &initialValue );
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you have declared an `int*` but not given it anything to point to.  What you need to do is initialize it with a memory location (error checknig omitted)

```
int* c = new int();
...
*c = d;  // Now works
```

Later on though you'll need to make sure to free this memory since it's an allocated resource.

A better solution though is to use references.  Pointers have several nasty attributes including unitialized values, `NULL`, need to free, etc ...  Most of which aren't present on references.  Here is an example of how to use references in this scenario.

```
void add (int a, int& c) {
   int d;
   d = a + 1;
   c = d;
   cout << "c = " << c << endl; 
}

int c;
add(4, c);
```

Comment: In C++, using `malloc` is almost certainly the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @Mike, agreed.  Only read the problem code and assumed it was a C question.  Updated

Answer (score 3):

You never allocate any memory to the pointer `c`. Pointers must refer to valid memory, and you must allocate that memory yourself with a call to `new`, e.g. write

```
int* c = new int();
```

within the `add` function. Now `c` points to a valid block of memory that is large enough to hold an `int`. When you are done with that memory, call `delete c` to deallocate it and release it back to the system.

Comment: The question is tagged C++, so using `malloc` would be a very bad idea.

Comment: Well, not a bad idea (malloc is perfectly legal in C++) but not the best idea. Will fix, though.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because c is an uninitialized pointer, so it is undefined behaviour.